# PyObjC development with Xcode 3.2

Tags: python, xcode, pyobjc

Xcode 3.2 has removed the default templates for the scripting languages (Ruby, Python etc). How do I find these templates to use in Xcode 3.2? Would I need to add anything else to Xcode to support working with and 'building' PyObjC programs?

Additionally, is there any documentation and/or resources that would help me get into PyObjC (and Cocoa), taking into account I am already a Python guy?

Comment: I'm a python guy too, and I've been learning Cocoa.  I don't think you'll find a better way to get into PyObjC then to ignore Python the time to learn Cocoa and Objective-C then come back to Python and PyObjC after you understand it.  Unfortunately, Cocoa is a very un-pythonic framework, and there isn't much in the way of dedicated PyObjC education materials.  If you learn Cocoa/ObjC first, you'll be so happy to get back to Python afterwards and PyObjC will just be Python access to the Cocoa frameworks you learned.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Apple now encourages people to get the templates directly from the PyObjC project. There's a nice thread of explanation archived on [Cocoabuilder](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/message/xcode/2009/8/31/30205), with the following advice from bbum:

> You'll need to download and install the templates from the PyObjC
>   repository or web site.
>
> The templates were pulled from the release because the template
>   development moves at a different pace & schedule than the Xcode
>   releases.  Too often, the templates have been out of date by the time
>   the discs were pressed.

The [PyObjC website](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/) has both the templates for download, and great documentation/tutorials to get up and going.

---

Edit: Being a bit more specific, here's what I have done to get PyObjC working in Snow Leopard:

- Using the Finder, I went to `Go > Connect to Server...` and connected to http://svn.red-bean.com/pyobjc/trunk/pyobjc/pyobjc-xcode/ as a guest.
- I then made a folder called `Xcode` on my local system at `~Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/`. (You may already have this folder, but I hadn't customized anything for myself yet).
- I copied the `File Templates` folder from the red-bean server into my new Xcode folder.
- Copied the `Project Templates` folder to some other place, for example, the Desktop.
- Using the Terminal, navigated to the temporary Project Templates folder on my Desktop and ran this command to "build" the template.:

> $ cd ~/Desktop/Project\ Templates/
>
> $ ./project-tool.py -k -v --template ~/Desktop/Project\ Templates/Cocoa-Python\ Application/CocoaApp.xcodeproj/TemplateInfo.plist Cocoa-Python\ Application ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project\ Templates/Cocoa-Python\ Application

- Repeat for the other templates:

> $./project-tool.py -k -v --template ~/Desktop/Project\ Templates/Cocoa-Python\ Document-based\ Application/CocoaDocApp.xcodeproj/TemplateInfo.plist Cocoa-Python\ Document-based\ Application/ ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project\ Templates/Cocoa-Python\ Document-based\ Application
>
> $ ./project-tool.py -k -v --template ~/Desktop/Project\ Templates/Cocoa-Python\ Core\ Data\ Application/CocoaApp.xcodeproj/TemplateInfo.plist Cocoa-Python\ Core\ Data\ Application/ ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project\ Templates/Cocoa-Python\ Core\ Data\ Application
>
> $ ./project-tool.py -k -v --template ~/Desktop/Project\ Templates/Cocoa-Python\ Core\ Data\ Document-based\ Application/CocoaDocApp.xcodeproj/TemplateInfo.plist Cocoa-Python\ Core\ Data\ Document-based\ Application/ ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project\ Templates/Cocoa-Python\ Core\ Data\ Document-based\ Application

- I launched Xcode. The templates are now located under the "User Templates" section of the `New Project...` and `New File...` windows.

The default project built out of the box (no need to install anything else from the PyObjC project, or py2app). I cobbled up a silly program with one button and an action, and it worked beautifully, including integration with Interface Builder (I was able to control-drag to wire up actions and outlets).

I also recently stumbled across a [series of "Getting Started" tutorials](http://scottr.org/blog/tags/pyobjc/) on a blog that seemed quite useful for beginners. The author appears to have put a lot of effort into the "Building Cocoa GUIs in Python with PyObjC" series (currently in 6 parts).

Comment: Unfortunately, even after custom-installing the templates like mentioned above, you may run into troubles with XCode 3.2 and IB. For me, none of the RubyCocoa/PyObjC features that connect IB and XCode together are working – Apple seems to have dropped enthusiasm for these bridges only one release after advertising them.

Comment: I haven't had that experience, I'm afraid. IB is noticing new objects, and outlets and actions in those objects quite well.

Comment: These instructions didn't work for me until I ran the Python script referenced in the README.

Comment: Many thanks, erickw... while the instructions I originally posted did work, I didn't look closely enough at the target names and the application delegate name. I've amended my instructions to include the information in the README.

Comment: After running the commands above, I had to go to the "Project Templates" folder, create the "Cocoa-Python" folder and move the 4 template folders into the new one. Only after that the templates appeared in Xcode. I suppose, Xcode wants a compulsory "template group" folder. I reckon the commands above could be amended to include this change.

Answer (score 4):

Check out this blog posting... fixed it perfectly for me: http://ioanna.me/2009/09/installing-pyobjc-xcode-templates-in-snow-leopard/

Answer (score 1):

Xcode has been changed, this is the way you do it:

1. Download the templates from https://github.com/gregneagle/Xcode4CocoaPythonTemplates
2. Copy the two folders, File Templates and Project Templates to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates`. If you don't have this folder already create it.
3. When you open Xcode and create a new project, you will see a new section called "Cocoa-Python" with the 4 templates.