# pyobjc, out of date?

Tags: python, xcode, pyobjc

I basically want to re ask  [PyObjC development with Xcode 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414727/pyobjc-development-with-xcode-3-2) except for Xcode 4.  Is pyobjc still something that can be used?

Comment: The following Stack Overflow question should help:

[PyObjC on Xcode 4][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843508/pyobjc-on-xcode-4